# How to set default pageload timeout in Watir?

Tags: timeout, watir

I have a page that I'd like to raise error if it loads too slow.
Is there some method for **Watir** analogous to **Watir-Webdriver**'s:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 10
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, http_client: client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir-Classic does not have an API for controlling how long to wait for a page to load.

When clicking a link or using the `goto` method, the [Browser#wait](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/browser.rb#L584-L638) method is called. This will block execution until the page is loaded. It is hard-coded to timeout if the page does not load in 5 minutes:

```
def wait(no_sleep=false)
  @xml_parser_doc = nil
  @down_load_time = 0.0
  interval = 0.05
  start_load_time = ::Time.now

  Timeout::timeout(5*60) do
    ...
end
```

**Solution 1 - Use Timeout**

If you only need to change timeout for a small number of scenarios, the simplest option may be to use the Timeout library.

For example, www.cnn.com takes 9 seconds to load on my computer. However, to only wait up to 5 seconds, you can wrap the `goto` (or `click`) method in an extra timeout:

```
Timeout::timeout(5) do
  browser.goto 'www.cnn.com'
end
#=> execution expired (Timeout::Error)
```

**Solution 2 - Monkey patch Browser#wait**

If you want the change to apply to all pages, you could overwrite the Browser#wait method to use a different timeout. For example, overwriting it to only be 5 seconds:

```
require 'watir-classic'

module Watir
  class Browser
    def wait(no_sleep=false)
      @xml_parser_doc = nil
      @down_load_time = 0.0
      interval = 0.05
      start_load_time = ::Time.now

      # The timeout can be changed here (it is in seconds)
      Timeout::timeout(5) do
        begin
          while @ie.busy
            sleep interval
          end

          until READYSTATES.has_value?(@ie.readyState)
            sleep interval
          end

          until @ie.document
            sleep interval
          end

          documents_to_wait_for = [@ie.document]
        rescue WIN32OLERuntimeError # IE window must have been closed
          @down_load_time = ::Time.now - start_load_time
          return @down_load_time
        end

        while doc = documents_to_wait_for.shift
          begin
            until READYSTATES.has_key?(doc.readyState.to_sym)
              sleep interval
            end
            @url_list << doc.location.href unless @url_list.include?(doc.location.href)
            doc.frames.length.times do |n|
              begin
                documents_to_wait_for << doc.frames[n.to_s].document
              rescue WIN32OLERuntimeError, NoMethodError
              end
            end
          rescue WIN32OLERuntimeError
          end
        end
      end

      @down_load_time = ::Time.now - start_load_time
      run_error_checks
      sleep @pause_after_wait unless no_sleep
      @down_load_time
    end
  end
end

browser.goto 'www.cnn.com'
#=> execution expired (Timeout::Error)
```

You could put the timeout value into a variable so that it can be dynamically changed.